# Why won't enum trigger the default option?

Tags: c#, enums

EDIT:

The program still does not work as it is supposed to. I tried to implement the suggested changes, which seemed to be the solution indeed. However, now any input into the programme leads to the default statement. What are we doing wrong?

NEW CODE WITH CHANGES BELOW:

```
public class Processor

{
    public void DisplayEmployers()
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Select an option");
        Console.WriteLine("1. Lawyer");
        Console.WriteLine("2. Admin");
        Console.WriteLine("3. Receptionist");

        Console.ReadLine();


    }
    public enum Staff { Lawyer, Admin, Receptionist, UnsupportedValue }

    public void ChooseTypeOfEmployer()
    {
        Staff s = (Staff.UnsupportedValue);
        switch (s)
        {
            case Staff.Lawyer:
                ProvideLogin();
                break;
            case Staff.Admin:
                ProvideLogin();
                break;
            case Staff.Receptionist:
                ProvideLogin();
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
                break;
        }
    }



    public void ProvideLogin()
    {

        string username, password;

        Console.WriteLine("Please provide username to access the system");

        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input a username: ");
            username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Input as password: ");
            password = Console.ReadLine();
            {
```

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? When/why were you expecting the default branch to execute here?

Comment: " now any input into the programme leads to the default statement" looks like you've hard-coded `s` to be `Staff.UnsupportedValue` and are not using the user input at all.

Comment: Also, if the posted answer solved your initial problem but now you have a _new_ problem, that should be  anew _question_. Otherwise the posted comment and answer makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

Because you already handled all available values.
Try the next case:

```
public enum Staff { Lawyer, Admin, Receptionist, UnsupportedValue }

public void ChooseTypeOfEmployer()
{
    Staff s = (Staff.UnsupportedValue);
    switch (s)
    {
        case Staff.Lawyer:
            ProvideLogin();
            break;
        case Staff.Admin:
            ProvideLogin();
            break;
        case Staff.Receptionist:
            ProvideLogin();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            break;
    }
}
```

++ you may to simplify you code

```
public void ChooseTypeOfEmployer()
{
    Staff s = (Staff.UnsupportedValue);
    switch (s)
    {
        case Staff.Lawyer:
        case Staff.Admin:
        case Staff.Receptionist:
            ProvideLogin();
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! We spent about two hours trying to fix this yesterday, with no luck. Really appreciate your help Den! Now it runs :)